# Apache Abdera Client - Posting/Putting

Tags: client, atom-feed, apache-abdera

Looking for help using the Apache Abdera Atom Client.  I am trying to post and put files to a feed but I am getting a 400 error saying that the content type must be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check where you are posting too. Abdera is used to post ATOM-XML format. It looks like you try to post to the same URL your web form is posting to, which would be a HTML submission a.k.a. `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Check with the blog server software if and where they support the ATOM publishing protocol.